# Structure to store pointer array and size

Tags: objective-c, arrays, pointers, opengl-es, struct

I'm just starting to learn OpenGL ES for the iPhone, and I wanted to create some custom methods to generate my own vertices in the form of `GLfloat` arrays, which must be passed as `GLfloat *` pointers.

In the method: `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gCubeVertexData), gCubeVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);`, it's necessary to get the size of the array, so I wanted to pass in the size of my custom array. I'm aware this isn't possible with pointers to arrays, but I'm also aware that there are several workarounds.

The one I had in mind was using a structure with the array inside of it like this:

```
#ifndef QuickBlueprint_GLfloatWithSize_h
#define QuickBlueprint_GLfloatWithSize_h

typedef struct {
    GLfloat *vertices;
    NSUInteger size;
} GLfloatWithSize;

#endif
```

And then using it in my class like this:

```
@interface MeasurableObject : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, assign) double length;
@property(nonatomic, assign) double width;
@property(nonatomic, assign) double height;
@property(nonatomic, assign) GLfloatWithSize vertices;

@end
```

Then, I'll have a constructor which initializes the `vertices` array inside of the `GLfloatWithSize` relative to the `length`, `width`, and `height` fields, and sets the `size` of that object to `sizeof(vertices)`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your solution looks rather good to me

Comment: @AnthonyKong haha thanks. I haven't tried it yet, but that's good to hear support from a reputable source.